# Parameter 5 of constructor in QueueServiceImpl required a bean of type QuotationDetailProxy that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

When try to up my application it get an above error. This thing happen when i import the
**private final QuotationDetailProxy quotationDetailProxy;** this line. I Also add the **@RequiredArgsConstructor**  this anotation to. I can't find any solution for this error when I'm trying to fix this I can't find any solutions. This is an Interface. help me with this.

**QuotationDetailProxy InterFace**

````
 public interface QuotationDetailProxy {

    default ResponseEntity<WrapperQuotationSummary> getFallbackDetails(Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(WrapperQuotationSummary.builder()
                .error(Error.builder()
                        .status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value())
                        .message(e.getMessage())
                        .build())
                .build());
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/quotation-summary-service/quotation-summary/job-no/{jobNo}")
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "muwIsfDataSyncApi", fallbackMethod = "getFallbackDetails")
    ResponseEntity<WrapperQuotationSummary> getQuotationSummaryByJobNo(@PathVariable String jobNo);
 }

1. **QueueServiceImpl Class**

@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Service
public class QueueServiceImpl implements QueueService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient;
    private final CustomerService customerService;
    private final TokenUtil tokenUtil;
    @Value("${application.isf.web-service-base-url}")
    private String webServiceBaseUrl;
    private final QuotationDetailProxy quotationDetailProxy;
}```


I want to up my service with out error help for that.
````

Comment: And where is the implementation of interface QuotationDetailProxy?

Comment: no any implementation for interface . If I cant access this in QueueServiceImpl class?